# Create responsive, resizing, centered DockedCell

Tags: front-end, customization, stylesheet

I was trying to define the same decorative toolbar as it is pictured [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToToolbars.html) in stylesheet. I succeed to do so. Now, I want to define custom decorative toolbar in the *Default* stylesheet using the same approach.  
  
 I used this code in *cell expression* form

```
Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[image] /. {(ImageSize -> {___, ___}) -> (ImageSize -> \{1399, 24})}], "DockedCell", Background -> White, ImageMargins -> 0, CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, CellFrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}] // CellPrint
```

Please note that instead of "`image`" in the code I used actual [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUcCA.jpg).  
 I copied this part from code above

```
RasterBox[CompressedData["1:eJ....SPo="], {{0, 232}, {1833, 0}}, {0, 255},
      ColorFunction->RGBColor] (*"1:eJ....SPo=" - too long to show*)
```

to

```
Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"], Editable->True, 
CellInsertionPointCell->FEPrivate`FrontEndResource[
"FEExpressions", "CellInsertionMenu"],
DockedCells->{Cell[BoxData[GraphicsBox[TagBox[place for code above,
BoxForm`ImageTag["Byte", Interleaving -> True, ColorSpace -> "RGB"], 
Selectable -> False], BaseStyle -> "ImageGraphics", 
ImageSize -> {1399, 250}, 
ImageSizeRaw -> {1399, 250}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1399}, {0, 250}}]]]}]
```

placed in the custom stylesheet notebook in the section *Style Enviroment Names*, *Working*.

The problem is that the docked decorative toolbar is not scalable in contrast to created decorative toolbar in notebook.
[image]

I put the corresponding notebook file and stylesheet notebook [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bf8ixedpabmws4b/AACBt6r8VeUg_KY8gesMCiZUa?dl=0)  
I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Sorry but I’m not entirely sure what your issue is. How do you need it to scale and in response to what? I think the issue is likely resolvable, whatever it is, I just don’t know what it is :)

Comment: @b3m2a1 The issue is that the toolbar at the top (the one defined in the stylesheet) does not behave in the same way as the other (at the "bottom"  ) toolbar created in the notebook. The other toolbar can adapt to the notebook window ( the window can be maximized, size changed and the bottom toolbar nicely follows this change of window). The issue can be seen in the picture - not all logos are displayed or only the part of the logo is displayed at the top toolbar.

Comment: Okay it sounds to me like you just want it to recenter and shrink itself. Is this right? If so I have an easy fix.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes, I think this will solve the problem.

Comment: Okay. I’ll help you with this tomorrow when I have access to Mathematica. The trick will be to wrap the expression in `Pane` and use ``ImageSize->FEPrivate`Part[FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize], 1]``, `ImageSizeAction->”ShrinkToFit”`, and `Alignment->Center` but I’ll need to debug that and get it all working just right.

Comment: That would be great! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. First we'll use this as our `DockedCell` expression:

```
newDockedCell =
  Cell[
   BoxData@ToBoxes@
     Pane[
      Import["https://i.imgur.com/LUIaEdC.png"],
      ImageSize ->
       {
        FEPrivate`Part[
         FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], 
          WindowSize],
         1],
        Automatic
        },
      ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit",
      Alignment -> Center
      ]
   ];
```

Then just add these style edits to the stylesheet however you like. This is my preferred short-hand (using custom package-level functions), but the easiest thing is just to do it manually as you have done:

```
StyleSheetEdit[
 "Notebook",
 DockedCells ->
  newDockedCell,
 "MakeCell" -> True
 ]

StyleSheetEdit[
 "DockedCell",
 {
  CellFrameMargins -> 0,
  Background -> White
  },
 "MakeCell" -> True
 ]
```

The key here is this:

```
FEPrivate`Part[
 FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], 
  WindowSize],
 1]
```

That will be computed by the front-end directly and give the notebook width.

By setting these:

```
ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit",
Alignment -> Center
```

The [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html) will force the content to be centered and take on that size and shrink if constrained.

You can see from these that it works:

[image: small]

[image: medium]

[image: large]

#### Getting this into the stylesheet:

This can be a little annoying to add to the stylesheet, so here's an effective way to do this:

- Go to the stylesheet
- Find the style `CellObject` for `"Notebook"`. This can be most easily gotten via `PreviousCell` or `NextCell`.
- Run this:

```
SetOptions[thatCell, DockedCells->newDockedCell]
```

- Select that cell and toggle Show Expression on and off

It should work after that

Comment: @Moonwalk see the update for getting it into the stylesheet

Comment: Thank you for having patience with me. In the third step I should wrap `thatCell` around with `SetOptions[ ,DockedCells->newDockedCell]` **in the stylesheet notebook**. So the expression will look like `SetOption[Cell[StyleData["Notebook"]...], DockedCells->Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Pane....]`. Am I right?

Comment: @Moonwalk no `thatCell` is the `CellObject`. For instance to find that you can run `PreviousCell[]` right below it. Or you can simply put the cursor right below the target cell and run `SetOptions[PreviousCell[], ...]`

Comment: Thank you again. It is working :)